# Fix ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

Trying to drop a unique constraint I've got such error:

```
ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys
```

How to find the list of foreign keys by which my unique constraint is referenced?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
select * from all_constraints 
where constraint_type='R' and r_constraint_name='YOUR_CONSTRAINT';
```